# Oracle - Get non empty values

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to get records from table where column value is not empty.

Assume  the following data points

```
**my_table (table_name)**

**my_column(column_name)**
abc
def
null
```

xyz

So I want to find records which are not empty or null. Basically my output has to be

```
abc
def
xyz
```

What I tried is

```
select * from my_table where my_column!=null & my_column!='';
```

This is returning 0 records

So I tried searching around and found Oracle treats blank string as null and used the following query

```
select * from my_table where trim(my_column) is not null;
```

This returned me all the results except record having null value.

I want even the empty string to disappear from the results. I tried all the possible combinations from above but am not getting desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `my_column` is a `VARCHAR2`, it sounds like you just want

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
 WHERE my_column IS NOT NULL
```

You'd never want to check whether `my_column = null` or `my_column != null`.  Regardless of the value of `my_column`, those predicates will always evaluate to false.  No value is ever equal to `NULL` and no value is ever unequal to `NULL`, not even another `NULL` value.  Oracle does not have the concept of an empty string.  You'd either have a `NULL` or you'd have a string with one or more spaces or some other filler character.  So there is no need to check whether the value is empty, just check whether it is `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks Justin. The only problem with this query is it does not evaluate blank value as null as it's mentioned out there in many places on web. I even tried modifying query you provided SELECT *
  FROM my_table
 WHERE trim(my_column) IS NOT NULL;    This still gives me empty string as output

Comment: @user2686860 - What does `select dump(my_column) from my_table` show you is actually stored in that column?  It appears that the row in question has something other than spaces in it.

Comment: Interesting. It is showing me Typ=1 Len=1: 30. No clue what that is.

Comment: @user2686860 - That's telling you that the row in question is not `NULL` and is not blank.  It contains a single character, CHR(30).  That's the "record separator" character (from http://www.asciitable.com/).  You could look for rows that have this character `select * from my_table where my_column = chr(30)`.  Or you could trim that character rather than trimming spaces `select * from my_table where trim( chr(30) from my_column ) is null`.

Comment: Thanks I think you have answered my question.